# Raw types to preserve low coupling

Tags: java, oop

I'm building a web service to provide data for an app I'm building. Because I was sick and tired of SQL I decided to try some different approaches and after some experiments decided on neo4j. I already had some entities classes, let's call them `A`, `B` & `C`. Now to separate the persistence from these entities I provide an abstraction layer on top of the database. It allows me to switch back to SQL or something completely different like rethinkdb later on if neo4j ends up scaling badly or whatever. The abstraction layer is an interface named `DBAdaptor<MetaObject>` with `MetaObject` a type variable. `NeoAdaptor<NeoMeta>` implements this interface just as a hypothetical `SQLAdaptor<SQLMeta>` would. The interface provides a load of methods which take A, B & C as parameters and return objects of this type eg `createA(some parameters):A<NeoMeta>`. `addAToB(A<NeoMeta> a, B<NeoMeta> b):void`. ...

Now, A through C extend the `DBObject<MetaObject>` class which allows the adaptor to associate metadata to an object. In the neo4j case the meta object associates the domain level object with the internal node ID (don't worry, this ID is shortlived and not part of the public api so reuse of node ID's is safe in this context). The whole idea was to hide this meta data from the user so that he can handle A, B and C without knowing what metadata the adaptor added to it (kind of like a decorator) however the java compiler obviously warns me that I'm using raw types. Obviously I'm not really using generic types as intended. How would you have solved this because apart from the warnings all through my code I find this a rather elegant solution.

One small note: I don't intend to be able to run two different db types at the same time so the class cast exceptions that would ensue in that case can be ignored.

Comment: Without seeing any code all I can say is get rid of raw types. According to JLS raw types may stop being supported in the future. And there must be a way to make the code generic.

Comment: You can try posting your question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a more thorough review of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the meta data from users of your domain classes `A`, `B` or `C`, don't have them extend `DBObject<MetaObject>` as it will have the opposite effect: exposing the `DBObject` interface to users. In general, it is bad to have domain classes depend on a persistence layer because changes in the persistence layer will ripple through to those classes and you want your domain to be rather stable.

Comment: But that's the point. This system avoids that. There isn't an actual dependency there only the appearance of one. In the logic A through B are handled in a way that's loose from the db (by referring to them as raw type elements, hence the warnings). The adaptor can be changed to any other db without touching the logic.

Comment: @MichielAriens How is `class A extends DBObject<MetaObject>` not a dependency? ;) Please provide actual code we can hack on, that will be more precise.